# fullcalendar not showing correctly in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, fullcalendar

I'm using Laravel framework and I'm very new to it.

Right now I'm trying to put in the Fullcalendar plugin, which I've done it before in other frameworks (Codeigniter, Play framework) and it worked amazingly.

However in Laravel, it doesn't seem to work like how it suppose to. The calendar doesn't show correctly, the prev and next buttons not show up, and the events not showing.

Please help

Here is my code. I'm using mockup events on the frontend.

```
$('#schedule').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    right: '',
    center: '',
    left: 'prev,next title weekNumber'
  },
  titleFormat: "D MMMM YYYY [(สัปดาห์ที่ 1 ของ 12)]",
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  aspectRatio: 1,
  events: events,
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
    var content = '<div class="fc-title">'+event.title+'</div>';
    content += '<div class="fc-desc">'+event.description+'</div>'
    element.find('.fc-content').html(content);
    },
    eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        $(this).append('<div class="event-hover"><div class="hover-pointer"></div><div>'+event.hoverContent+'</div></div>')
    },
    eventMouseout: function( event, jsEvent, view ) {
        $('.event-hover').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is how it look like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweduCwUSmusZ3haSmIzM1Rhbk0/view?usp=sharing

And this is how it suppose to look like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweduCwUSmusT3JlajA2YlEtSEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is related to JS & HTML I assume judging by the snippet above. Have you opened the console and looked for any errors? How are you loading the library etc? Does the calendar call an endpoint to retrieve data, have you investigated that?

Comment: @SamV I've checked my console, and there're no errors. The plugin seems to load in fine because it seems to be half working.

I haven't done any changes, just moving from one framework to another. The calendar is not calling any functions because I've created an array of events and used it directly.

Comment: If you comment out the `events: event` line, does it work? Because unless something is wrong with the events or eventRender, that code works fine for me. I don't know anything about laravel but the FC code doesn't look like it's causing a problem.

Comment: @slicedtoad I've tried that and it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now found an answer to this.
It's not because of laravel.

I've added the fullcalendar.print.css into it that's why the css was messed up. So I've now removed it and it works perfect.

Thanks anyway for all the help